# Зачем нужны виртуальные функции C++

Tags: c++

Натолкнулся на тему виртуальных функций, но не совсем понял, зачем они нужны и как правильно их применять, зачем нужен виртуальный деструктор и т.д.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

По поводу виртуального деструктора - он нужен всегда, если есть хоть одна виртуальная функция, иначе не будут вызваны все деструкторы.

Зачем нужны виртуальные функции? Для обеспечения полиморфизма - одного из базовых китов ООП, чтобы по ссылке/указателю на объект не определять его тип самостоятельно с помощью if'ов, а дать это делать компилятору и/или в runtime. Можно ещё в википедии [почитать](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: >> иначе будут вызваны все деструкторы.
 
Правильно: иначе НЕ будут вызваны все деструкторы

Comment: исправился